# DOMDocument - Create book, load chapters and append

Tags: xml, domdocument, php-7.3

Need to use DOMDocument to construct a book with loaded and appended chapters. Each chapter would be stored in separate xml file. Below would create the root book and append the first child chapter_1. I understand that the "foreach"-loop will never load any other chapters since it is hardcoded for the chapter_1.

The aim is to solve the problem using DOMDocument to take care of proper tag wrapping. I know I could in this case use PHP include for all the chapters, and include root at start and end, (as a wrapper).

**Question:**

What would I need to change in the for-loop to be able to append a growing amount of chapters? Would I need to specify an array first and perform a "foreach" -loop to iterate over the array?

My code:

**File: merge.php**

```
<?php

$book = new DOMDocument();
$book->load('1_build_block_(book).xml');

$chapter_1 = new DOMDocument();
$chapter_1->load('2_build_block_(chapter_1).xml');

$chapter_2 = new DOMDocument();
$chapter_2->load('3_build_block_(chapter_2).xml');

// chapter_3, chapter_4, etc...

/**
 * Merge chapters into book.
 */

foreach ($chapter_1->childNodes as $child) {
    $book->documentElement->appendChild(
        $book->importNode($child, TRUE)
    );
}

echo $book->saveXML();
$book->saveHTMLFile("result.xml");
```

**File: 1_build_block_(book).xml**

```
<book></book>
```

**File: 2_build_block_(chapter_1).xml**

```
<chapter_1></chapter_1>
```

**File: 3_build_block_(chapter_2).xml**

```
<chapter_2></chapter_2>
```

**Result:**

```
<book>
  <chapter_1></chapter_1>
</book>
```

**Wanted result:**

```
<book>
  <chapter_1></chapter_1>
  <chapter_2></chapter_2>
</book>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use for example [preg_grep](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) in combination with [scandir](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) to get the files with the specific filenames.

If the files are in the same dir, you could use this pattern to get the chapters only, where `\d+` matches 1 or more digits.

```
^\d+_build_block_\(chapter_\d+\)\.xml$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y9lWVp/1)

```
$book = new DOMDocument();
$book->load('1_build_block_(book).xml');
$path = "./";
$chapters = preg_grep('~^\d+_build_block_\(chapter_\d+\)\.xml$~', scandir("./"));

foreach ($chapters as $chapter) {
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->load($chapter);
    foreach ($doc->childNodes as $child) {
        $book->documentElement->appendChild(
            $book->importNode($child, TRUE)
        );
    }
}

echo $book->saveXML();
$book->saveHTMLFile("result.xml");
```

Output

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<book><chapter_1/><chapter_2/></book>
```

Comment: Updated the question, with aim to solve with DOMDocument , if possible.

Comment: @Toolbox The answer uses DOMDocument. Which part do you want to use differently?

Comment: I guess it answers the question. My mistake was to use the book as an example. The "chapters" illustrated childs and could in my real code have variations of other names. I will go ahead and approve and open another question.